# How to find the error when there is no error-information (problem hosting an ASP.Net MVC 3 App)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-3

All we get when publishing our ASP.Net MVC 3 app is this:

[image: Weird error]

You may also [relive the error here](http://v2.presenta.nu/).

There's no error message or anything. We've seen this once before, when the connection-string was invalid. This time however, we're sure that is not the problem.

How should we procceed to "debug" this app? It works fine on the dev server.

Comment: Are you sure you are not double compressing (gzip/deflate) your page?

Comment: @Bcelik Not really, I'll investigate!

Comment: I had same kind of output when i was using a compression filter, and i forgot to turn off IIS page compression. That made it double compress the page. Once by my attribute and then again by IIS.

Comment: @Bcelik that might really be why I cannot see the error message, because we are also using a custom attribute for compression! It do however work now when we uploaded System.Web.Razor as marcind suggested in his answer (which is kinda weird).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm seeing the following error when I visit the link you provided:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

This error indicates that you do not have MVC 3 installed on the target server and did not deploy the right set of binaries with your app. Read the following for more information: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/18/running-an-asp-net-mvc-3-app-on-a-web-server-that-doesn-t-have-asp-net-mvc-3-installed.aspx

(Btw, is your app doing localization, different response encodign, etc? maybe that's why you are seeing these garbled responses).

Comment: How is it that you're seeing that?

Comment: Just curious, how come you see it and we don't? We'll add the library and try again, then let you know if it is working or not!

Comment: I have no idea why I could see the message. It's your server :)

Answer (score 0):

That is truly bizarre! If you have console access to the server, I would suggest logging in through Remote Desktop and executing the page there. You may get the "yellow screen of death", and be able to debug from there.